# Can you use jQuery ajax to retrieve data from Webservice?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I'm attempting to retrieve data from a SQL Server database, and using jQuery ajax to do it with. I need to bring this data into some jqPlot charts, and figured this was the best way to do that. If there is a better way, let me know.

Here is my current code:

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".datepicker").datepicker();

$(".submitButton").click(handleSubmitButton);

});      //end of document ready

function handleSubmitButton() {

   var AnDParms = new Object();
   AnDParms.startDate = $('.start-date').val();
   AnDParms.endDate = $('.end-date').val();
   AnDParms.facility = $('.FacilityDDL').val();

   var DTO = { 'parameters': AndParms };

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
       url: "GetAdmitsDischarges.asmx.cs/GetAandD",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data) {
           alert("Data: " + data.d);
           // do chart stuff here.
       },
       error: function (data) {
           alert("Error!" + data.d);
       } //end of success
   }); //end of ajax call
} //end of handleSubmitButton function
```

Web service (`GetAdmitsDischarges.asmx.cs`):

```
namespace DashboardTest2010
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class GetAdmitsDischarges : WebService
    {
        public class AnDParms
        {
            public string startDate { get; set; }
            public string endDate { get; set; }
            public string facility { get; set; }
        }

        public class AnDReturns
        {
            public string Admits { get; set; }
            public string Discharges { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetAandD(AnDParms parameters)
        {
           //StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
           AnDReturns resultsObj = new AnDReturns();
           resultsObj.Admits = "0";
           resultsObj.Discharges = "0";
           string results = "";

           string connect = (the data connection string)
           StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
           query.Append("Select 'Admissions' SeriesType,");
           //the rest of the query.

           using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
           {
               using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), conn))
               {
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", parameters.startDate.ToString());
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate", parameters.endDate.ToString());
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilityID", parameters.facility.ToString());

                   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                   if (rdr.HasRows)
                   {
                       while (rdr.Read())
                       {
                           if (rdr["SeriesType"].ToString() == "Admissions")
                           {
                               resultsObj.Admits = rdr["SeriesCount"].ToString();
                           }
                           if (rdr["SeriesType"].ToString() == "Discharges")
                           {
                               resultsObj.Discharges = rdr["SeriesCount"].ToString();
                           }
                       }
                       results = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultsObj);
                   }
               }
           }
           return results;
       }
   }
}
```

The mark up is just a simple page with 2 date fields (set to datepickers), 1 dropdown list (facility), and one submit button.  Here are my script tags to make sure I have everything I need to have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/DashboardTest.js"></script>
```

The "jquery.js" is the jquery that came with jqPlot.  I have to support IE 7+ (hence the json2.js) the DashboardTest.js is the javascript above.

Nothing happens when I run this, no alerts show up when I click the submit button.  Any help would be much appreciated.  My System Admin didn't allow me to install Fiddle, if you're wondering about that...

Comment: Did you check the javascript console and network tab in your browser tools for errors? Did you check to make sure the xhr request is what you would expect?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the web developer console in your web browser?

Comment: No errors in firebug Console.

Comment: @Jason P: I'm unsure what your asking about xhr request, is that something in Firebug?  OK, I looked up XHR and I'm unsure how to check that out...

Comment: @BradAtCC In Firebug, there is a "Net" tab, and after you click that, you can click the "XHR" button to filter and show only ajax requests. Look for your request there.

Comment: @Jason P: when I click the Submit button with net->XHR open, it says "0 requests"...I bet that's telling.

Comment: @BradAtCC Is your submit button causing a postback? You may need to add the `e` parameter to your `handleSubmitButton(e)` function, and call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the postback.

Comment: ok, that caused some stuff to happen: now the error alert is triggering, and am getting this error in the Firebug Console: "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:52242/GetAdmitsDischarges.asmx.cs/GetAandD?{%22parameters%22:{%22startDate%22:%2208/01/2013%22,%22endDate%22:%2208/31/2013%22,%22facility%22:%2234351%22}}"

Comment: @BradAtCC Good, I would do a little research on that error, and if you still can't get it, come back and ask a more specific question relating to that message. I don't have a solution for that one off the top of my head. Though on second thought, it could be related to windows authentication if you're using that.

Comment: I'm not using windows authentication, but thanks for your help...I'll do some more research, and post if I get stuck again...

Comment: Is "%22" = to double or single quote or a space??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While calling WebService, use `GetAdmitsDischarges.asmx` page for URL, not code-behind `GetAdmitsDischarges.asmx.cs` page.

Also 1 more thing. You're doing GET request, by default WebServices don't allow it. You may have to add

```
<webServices>
   <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
   </protocols>
</webServices>
```

to your web.config.

Comment: I got an " Unrecognized configuration section webServices." Does that addition to the web.config go at a certain place?

Comment: I moved it up to inside the last system.web, and that seemed to fix the above error, but now I'm getting this error:  "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:52242/GetAdmitsDischarges.asmx/GetAandD?{%22startDate%22:%2208/01/2013%22,%22endDate%22:%2208/31/2013%22,%22facility%22:%22855%22}"  I changed the code to get rid of the DTO, and just passed AandDParms to JSON.stringify...

Comment: Yes that web.config section has to be inside system.web. About the error - can you check Event log for any ASP.NET related errors? 500 is a very generic one, but event log can give more details. Also what parameters does the web service expect? Can you try running it as direct URL from a browser address bar?

Comment: I've glanced at the logs and can't understand where to look for any info that would be useful.  the parameters I was trying to pass was an object with three attributes startDate, endDate, and FacilityID.  I tried running it at the URL but since it returns and takes a complex types it wouldn't let me supply the values.  I'll try using variables instead of the parameter class (AnDParms)...

Comment: About event logs - make 500 error happen, then in event logs go into Windows Logs, Application Logs and look for the lates yellow exclamation point related to ASPNET errors

Comment: Another thing to try - start debugging your WebService, put a breakpoint at the entry point and make your AJAX call - go thru code step-by-step, see what bombs

Comment: I've tried to debug it, but break points are never hit...maybe that says something.

Comment: The last "yellow !" was like 2.5 hours ago, and does relate to me, it looks like that error was related to your answer above (before I removed the ".cs" from the call...but no more warnings have shown up since then in the App Log.

Comment: Apparently, a major problem with it was that I used type: "GET" instead of type: "POST"...

Comment: Glad it worked for you, thanks for marking my solution as answer. Ordinary GET should work for these kinds of calls as well, but if your data is complex as you said - POST is the answer